# Laravel Sync column toggle

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a project for my self and was wondering if there is a good solution for the following problem.

At the moment I am creating a user > role > permission system.
The idea is that when you're creating or updating a role, you can see all the permissions and use checkboxes to add te permission (Really simple).
But I want to add more checkboxes for Create, Read, Update and Delete (CRUD).

The setup at this moment is as follows:

Role table:
`string name`

Permission table:
`string name`

PermissionRole table:
`uint role_id, uint permission_id, boolean create, boolean read, boolean update, boolean delete`

To add the permissions to the role I am using the sync() method.

Example:

```
$role->permissions()->sync([1 => ['create' => 1, 'update' => 1], 2 => ['create' => 1]]);
```

And this works fine. But, when I am updating instead of inserting and for example I uncheck the checkbox create by the first permission the create won't be set to false, because the form doesn't send the create checkbox anymore.

Is there a way to use the sync method and let it set the not added fields to false by default?

Comment: You could map the input to a default value if it's missing from the request `$create = Request::input('create', 0);`. Because you want to update a  record, you're going to need to define those values before you persist them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build the array of properties before calling sync, for example

```
$crudPermission1 = [
    'create' => $request->has('permissions.1.create'),
    'read' => $request->has('permissions.1.read'),
    'update' => $request->has('permissions.1.update'),
    'delete' => $request->has('permissions.1.delete')
];

$role->permissions()->sync([1 => $crudPermission1]);
```

That was a simple example, you will need to build a loop for do it automatically for each permission.

You need to take in mind:

- If you don't specify the column `update`, it will remain untouched.
- To have an unchecked checkbox, you need to check if it comes from request with `$request->has('checkbox-name');`